# Data macro (trigger) to apply constraints when inputting records into an Access table

Tags: sql, triggers, ms-access-2010, constraints

I am developing a simple database for students to register courses using Microsoft Access 2010. I have 4 tables: Student, Register, Course, and Section (1 Course can have many Sections).

Then, there is a criteria that a student can only take up to 5 courses. Hence, may I know that where and how can I include this constraint? I don't know how to use Macro. Please help me with that!

Btw, my relationship is: Student -> Register <- Section <- Course

Comment: Are you using a form to insert the data?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to make a form to for the registration. However, is it possible to make the constraint in the table? Or I have to set the constraint in the form? Then how to do it? I have no idea how to make this constraint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish your goal with a Before Change [data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx) on the [Register] table.

The simplest approach would be to use the `DCount()` function to count the existing rows in the table:

[image: DCountMacro.png]

That will work for INSERT/UPDATE operations performed from within Microsoft Access itself, but unfortunately it will **fail** with ...

> The function 'DCount' is not valid for expressions used in data macros.

... if we try to update the table from an external program such as a C# or VB.NET application.

A more robust solution would be to create a saved query named [CourseCountsByStudent] in Access

```sql
SELECT Register.StudentID, Count(Register.CourseID) AS CountOfCourseID
FROM Register
GROUP BY Register.StudentID;
```

and look up the corresponding count using the query instead of the `DCount()` function

[image: QueryMacro.png]

That approach will work in cases where the earlier one would fail.

---

### Additional example to match sample database

For sample data in tables

[Courses]

```
courseid  course
--------  ---------------------------------------
BC2402    Data Management & Business Intelligence
```

[Course_Sections]

```
sectiontid  courseid
----------  ---------
BC2402A     BC2402
BC2402B     BC2402
BC2402C     BC2402
```

[Register]

```
studentid  sectionid
---------  ---------
U1233333K  BC2402C
```

the following data macro code will check if the student is already registered in another section of the course.

[image: SectionCheck.png]

Trying to add another [Register] record like this

```
studentid  sectionid
---------  ---------
U1233333K  BC2402C
U1233333K  BC2402A
```

will return the error

> Student is already registered in section "BC2402C".

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the comment. However, I cannot find the function DCount() in my Microsoft Access 2010. Are there any problems with that? And, what if my Register table only contain 2 fields which are StudentID and SectionID? I think that if students register for 2 sections in the same course, it will lead to another problem as well. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @LucasVinhTran RE: DCount() - The function is an integral part of Access, but IntelliSense in the macro editor is probably excluding it because it is not fully supported in data macros (as my answer illustrates). The second (saved query) approach is better. RE: sections vs. courses - You could add another check to the macro to "Look Up A Record In" the Course table to get the CourseID, then use that to do another lookup on a saved query of Register INNER JOIN Sections to see if the student has already registered for another section of the course.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The Macro is quite new to me and I need more time to get familiar with it. However, thanks so much for your support. I will give a try.

Comment: @LucasVinhTran I have updated my answer with an additional example.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson: Thks, but I still can not able to do it. Access told me about something called "the identifier [...] could not be found". I think because of the relationship or sth like that. My relationship is: Student -> Register <- Section <- Course. Anw, my email is quangvinh0105@gmail.com. Is it possible that you could send your email to me so that I can send my work to you? I think it could be more easy to check :) If not, then it's ok. I will try to see the differences here :)

Comment: HELLO, ANYBODY HAVE ANY SUGGESTIONS? I AM STILL NOT ABLE TO DO IT :(

This is my file: http://www.mediafire.com/download/7oxbrhrrvhyh5bi/RegisterDatabase.accdb

Comment: @LucasVinhTran I have updated the second half of my answer to match your file. (I tested it on your file and it works.)  ...also, please don't shout.

Comment: @GordTompson: so sorry cuz i have stuck with this for more than a week, that's too bad :(. However, I follow exactly what you helped me but my file still does not work. It says that "the query failed to execute because the identifier 'Register.courseid' could not be found".

It's perhaps because there is no courseid field in the Register table. Could you send the file you tested to me so that I can compare? (quangvinh0105@gmail.com). 

Really really sorry for my slow on the uptake. Please help me with that! Thks so much.

Comment: @LucasVinhTran You can download my working example [here](http://wikisend.com/download/473550/RegisterDatabaseWithMacro.accdb).

Comment: @GordTompson: hi, I know the problem now. It's because you use the 'sectiontid' and I use the 'sectionid1'. Could you please explain the reason why? 

By the way, your first part was not match with my example as well. I think it was because you assumed that the relationship was Student -> Register <- Course. Hence, may I know that how to change the 1st part? 

I am sorry that I make a lot of inconveniences for you. But I really want to understand about this one :)

Comment: @LucasVinhTran RE: `sectiontid` - That is the actual name of the field in the [Course_Sections table](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5X8LK.png). Perhaps it's a typo, but that is its actual name. RE: the first part half of the answer - Just use `SELECT studentid, Count(sectionid) AS CountOfsectionid FROM Register
GROUP BY studentid` for the saved query and make the corresponding changes to the field names in the macro steps.

Comment: @GordTompson: Yes this is a typo mistake. I finished this part before seeing your comment :D. I really really appreciate your help! Thanks so so much :)